# MM experience - what does the MM stand for?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In a job description today I find the question:

Do you have Public Sector/MM experience?

So, before I answer that I have to know what the "MM experience" stands for. I looked over Google but I found no satisfying answer. Could anyone help, please?

Best regards
Michael

Comment: [AcronymFinder](https://www.acronymfinder.com/MM.html) is a general work of reference. But it offers lots of possible expansions, some more likely here than others. Probably not 'Mad Max' or 'Marilyn Monroe'.

Comment: Thanks for the support!

Comment: What country/region? It could mean 'middle management' or any of a number of things. But consider this: maybe knowing what 'MM' means is itself a qualification for the job -- anyone applying should already know.

Comment: [***MM stands for Material Management**, FI standard for Financial Accounting, SD stands for Sales and Distribution.*](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/12/31/integration-point-of-mm-fi-sd-in-sap-erp/) See also [*SAP SD/MM Consultant*](https://jobs.telegraph.co.uk/job/11480657/sap-sd-mm-consultant-opportunity-to-move-to-s-4hana/) in the "Jobs" section of *The Telegraph*. But basically, what @Jim said is quite right - if you don't know what the abbreviation means ***in context***, the job offer isn't aimed at you!

Comment: Multi-Media is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

It should be clear from the responses in the comments that "MM experience" is not a well-established term, and the answer depends highly on the context in which it was asked. I suggest seeking clarification from the person who used it.